# Player is lagging when moved around

Tags: python, pygame

I followed up a tutorial to make a platformer game in pygame and completed it. But when I try to make them with my own lines of code, the movement of the player is lagging. I don't know how to solve this. This is the player's code

```
import pygame
```

from settings import PLAYER_SPEED

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 64))
        self.image.fill((214, 52, 41))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
    def get_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
        self.rect.x += self.direction.x * PLAYER_SPEED
```

The player speed is 4 and the clock.tick is 60. Please help

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In a game You must have a game loop which handles the input and control the sprite movements.If every element check for key press, you are wasting time other than the bad architecture

Answer (score 0):

```
public float xMargin = 1f;        // Distance in the x axis the player can move before the camera follows
public float yMargin = 1f;        // Distance in the y axis the player can move before the camera follows
public float xSmooth = 8f;        // How smoothly the camera catches up with the target movement in the x axis
public float ySmooth = 8f;        // How smoothly the camera catches up with the target movement in the y axis
public Vector2 maxXY;             // The maximum X and Y coordinates the camera can have
public Vector2 minXY;             // The minimum X and Y coordinates the camera can have

private Transform player;        // Reference to the player's transform

void Awake () {

    // Setting up the reference
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
}

bool CheckXMargin() {

    // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the X asis is greater than the xMargin
    return Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - player.position.x) > xMargin;

} bool CheckYMargin() {

    // Returns true if the distance between the camera and the player in the Y asis is greater than the yMargin
    return Mathf.Abs (transform.position.y - player.position.y) > yMargin;
}


void FixedUpdate() {
    TrackPlayer();
}

void TrackPlayer () {

    // default coordinates of camera
    float targetX = transform.position.x;
    float targetY = transform.position.y;

    // If the player has moved beyond the margin, target should be a Lerp between the camera's current pos and the player's current pos.
    if(CheckXMargin())
        targetX = Mathf.Lerp (transform.position.x, player.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime);

    if(CheckYMargin())
        targetY = Mathf.Lerp (transform.position.y, player.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);

    // The target coordinates should not be larger than the max or smaller than the min
    targetX = Mathf.Clamp (targetX, minXY.x, maxXY.x);
    targetY = Mathf.Clamp (targetY, minXY.y, maxXY.y);

    // Set the camera's position to the target position with the same z component
    transform.position = new Vector3(targetX, targetY, transform.position.z);

}
```

Comment: The question relates to the pygame library and the Python programming language.